# Protractor Cucumber Typescript: Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

`enter code here`I am able to run the feature file if no parameters in the scenario. With parameter I been getting this    ? Given User has successfully navigated to the Manufacturing "DEV" Application
Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

```
     Given('User has successfully navigated to the Manufacturing {string} Application', function (string) {
       // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
       return 'pending';
     });
```

[feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfHfr.png)

[LoginSteps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9g8f.png)

[LoginPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1LiG.png)

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNlsh.png)

```js
feature:

Feature: Protractor Test
  
  @TEST
  Scenario Outline: Login Test
    Given User has successfully navigated to the Manufacturing "<ENV>" Application

    Examples:
    | ENV   |
    | DEV   |

LoginSteps.ts

import { browser, protractor } from "protractor";
import {LoginPage} from "../pages/LoginPage";
const { When, Then , Given} = require("cucumber");
const loginpage: LoginPage = new LoginPage();

Given('User has successfully navigated to the Manufacturing (.*?) Application.', async (env) => {
  await loginpage.OpenBrowser(env)

});



Loginpage.ts
import {browser, by, element, $, ElementFinder} from 'protractor';

export class LoginPage {

     OpenBrowser = async (env) => {
        switch (env) {
            case("DEV"):
                await browser.sleep(5000);
                await browser.get("https://angularjs.org/");

        }
    }
}

   

    enter code here
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Copy it and paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the regular expression the step in the step definition needs to be:

```
Given('User has successfully navigated to the Manufacturing "(.*?)" Application.', async (env) => { 
    await loginpage.OpenBrowser(env)
});
```